# partition a usb memory stick

Tags: partitioning

I'm trying to partition a 16GB memory stick so both partitions can be seen by windows.

I've created 2 partitions, 500 MB and 15.5 GB both FAT323. But windows only sees the 1st.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` when your memory stick is mounted?

Comment: Windows only sees the first partition on flash drives. I do not know of a way to change that. Linux will see all partitions, so just make a larger NTFS partition for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo -fdisk -l result

```
Partition table entries are not in disk order
Disk /dev/sdc: 16.0 GB, 16008609792 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1946 cylinders, total 31266816 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00019063
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048    30722047    15360000    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc2   *    30722048    31266815      272384    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I've only put in the usb stick as the block insert doesn't seem to work so I had to copy and paste each line.
But as windows doesn't see the other block this will do as the intent was to install 
    http://antivirusLivecd.4mlinux.com

onto the small partition but still have most of the stick available for copy between linux and windows.
so my problem is solved and explained

Thanks very much